# Pandas losing inheritance when subsetting dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, class

I made my own pandas class to add some custom methods, here's the code

```
Class Mypandas(pd.DataFrame): 
    def foo(sefl): 
        return self
```

When I run the following, I get an AttributeError saying 'DataFrame' object has no attribute

```
df = Mypandas(df)
df = df.query('count > 0')
df.foo()
```

I guess it's because I'm subsetting my df but as I instantiated Mypandas, should I still have access to df.foo()? Why is that? How can I counter this so I can still subset my df?

Comment: See these instructions: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures

Comment: `sefl` in `def foo(sefl)` is mispelled!